# Setting up APACHE-JAMES Server

Tags: java, ubuntu, email-server

I am trying to setup Apache-James Server on Ubuntu, in which I am getting the annoying error:

> JAVA_HOME not defined correctly
>
> We cannot execute

I have already referred to the documentations and set up the **PATH** and **JAVA_HOME** variables correctly in the **/etc/profile** file.
Upon calling echo, I get the values in the output screen. Where am I missing?

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_27
echo $PATH
$PATH:/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_27/bin
```

Please Help !!

Comment: I'm getting the same error trying to run maven on ubuntu.  Does that jdk path exist on your machine?  If you are running a command line, does using sudo help?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to set `JAVA_HOME` correctly,

Go into your terminal and type this :

```
whereis java
```

That will give you the path of the java installation then :

```
gedit /etc/bash.bashrc
```

(I'm using sun) add at the end of the file

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
```

Now you 've only have to reboot.